# Error loading pngs from a .bundle in Objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, png, bundle

I'm building a framework in my Xcode project. To build the framework, I created an aggregate target. The framework consists of the static library, header files, and bundle of .png assets, `MyFrameworkResources.bundle`. When I build the aggregate, everything is successfully created and the bundle exists in my Products directory.

Also in my Xcode project is a target Application. This application is for testing the framework products (static library, header files, and bundle). I've added the static library and `MyFrameworkResources.bundle` to the Target Dependencies of the target Application. I've also added `MyFrameworkResources.bundle` to Copy Bundle Resources in Build Phases of the target Application.

I can use all files from the static library just fine, but I get an error when trying to load resources from the bundle. This is how I'm loading assets from the bundle:

```
NSString *mainBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSString *frameworkBundlePath = [mainBundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFrameworkResources.bundle"];
NSBundle *frameworkBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:frameworkBundlePath];
NSLog(@"bundle: %@", frameworkBundle);

NSError *error;
[frameworkBundle loadAndReturnError:&error]; // <-- THIS RETURNS AN ERROR
NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[frameworkBundle pathForResource:@"AnyImage" ofType:@"tiff"]]; // <-- EDIT, USE "tiff", NOT "png"
```

When I log the bundle, I get this:

bundle: 
**NSBundle /Users/my_comp/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/blah-blah-blah/MyApp.app/MyFrameworkResources.bundle (not yet loaded)**

When I log the error, I get this:

error:
**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4 "The bundle “MyFrameworkResources” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located." UserInfo=0x7535ee0 {NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Try reinstalling the bundle., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be located., NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “MyFrameworkResources” couldn’t be loaded because its executable couldn’t be located., NSBundlePath=/Users/my_comp/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/blah-blah-blah/MyApp.app/MyFrameworkResources.bundle}**

So to double check, I cd'd into `/Users/my_comp/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/blah-blah-blah/MyApp.app/` on my computer, and the `MyFrameworkResources.bundle` was actually there. So now I'm at a loss. I've tried cleaning the aggregate target, cleaning the target Application, deleting the target Application, and no luck.

**Any idea why I can't load images from the bundle?** (sorry for the lengthy description)

Fyi, I've been using [this great tutorial](https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework#step-4-loading-bundle-resources) as a guideline to build the framework and bundle.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463484/ios-loading-xib-from-bundle-in-documents-directory maybe the same?

Comment: Hmm I think it's similar, but that asker is downloading the bundle from the internet, rather than being packaged with the Application. In any case I tried getting the path to the bundle in the same manner they did (eg `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSApplicationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)` and am seeing the same error as before :-/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah after struggling on this a bit more, I cd'd into `MyFrameworkResources.bundle` just to double check that all the assets were included. It turns out that Xcode renamed the .png files to .tiff files, and removed the retina assets. After further investigation, I discovered that **Xcode automatically combines the retina and non-retina .png files into a "one multi-page TIFF"**. Here's a [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5568317/931746).

Solution, use `ofType:@"tiff"` instead of `ofType:@"png"`:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[frameworkBundle pathForResource:@"AnyImage" ofType:@"tiff"]];
```

Comment: Also, I had problems loading `tiff` images from the bundle (some @2x images were not rendering properly). So I tried disabling the `tiff`s and used the `png`s instead. This worked as expected. To disabled Xcode combining pngs into tiffs, go to your target bundle's Build Settings and `COMBINE_HIDPI_IMAGES` to `NO`.