# Retina graphics not loading from NSBundle

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, nsbundle

I created a framework using the tutorial over at raywenderlich.com and also included a resource bundle with it. Inside of the bundle is a storyboard file and many images, all having a corresponding @2x file.

When I include this framework and bundle in my testing app, the storyboard loads fine when it's presented, but the retina graphics are not displayed. When I click the drop-down arrow on the bundle in the testing app, all the @2x files are there.

How do I get it so that the @2x graphics load? I heard the phone should detect them by itself, but they're not loading.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it is true, phone detects retina image by itself. Is your images in png format?

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode automatically combines the retina and non-retina .png files into a "one multi-page TIFF"**

Solution:

use `@"tiff"` instead of `@"png"`

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[yourBundle pathForResource:@"yourImage" ofType:@"tiff"]];
```

here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15445494/4152393)